# Business Objects - Summarising Data in a Separate Report

Tags: business-objects

I'm trying to make a neat 'front end' report tab (Summary) that just contains the summary information from another report tab (Report1) but I can't seem to get my summary working correctly.
I have some data (Report1) like so, where I have created a variable to flag if 'Value' is above 500:

```
ID    Value    Above  
1234   400     0  
2345   600     1  
3567   200     0  
5687   1000    1
```

So I want to sum up over 'Above' in a separate report tab (Summary). I can't find anything that works yet so any function ideas etc would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this:

=sum([Above]ForEach([ID]))

Answer (score 0):

Add a new query in the data provider which Counts the No of IDs with a value of 500 and more and use that Value to display in the main sheet.

Regards,
vijay